# screenshot from the second tab - puppeteer, nodejs

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, screenshot

I want to capture the screenshot of my page from the second tab, which is opened after clicking in the first tab. But code do nothing. Nodejs , Puppeteer
My code:

- code is safe for cloudfare checker.
- the second tab is safe and will pass the cloudfare test, but I can no longer continue in it, do something (for example, screenshot).
- if I put out targetFiter is ok for screenshot, but not safe to cloudfare
- the first page is only for starting
- element on landing page is set up [target="_blank"] - so after clicking it is opened in new tab - it is necessarily, because in the first tab it isn´t safe for cloudfare checker, only second, ...or others tabs
- this is problem´s part of code: click on element -> is opened new tab -> I want take a screeshot from this new page in new tab, but code "**do nothing**"

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())

const {executablePath} = require('puppeteer')

const targetFilter = (target) => { return !!target.url() || target.type() === 'popup'; };

async function runView() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
        headless: false,
        args: ['--no-sandbox'],
        executablePath: executablePath(),
        logLevel: 'debug',
        targetFilter: targetFilter,
    });

    let page1 = (await browser.pages())[0]; 
    
    await page1.goto('https://nonameblog2023.blogspot.com/p/dev.html', {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
        timeout: 30000,
    });
    await page1.waitForTimeout(5000);
  
    const redirectButton = '#articleContent > p:nth-child(5) > a';  
    await page1.waitForSelector(redirectButton);
    const elementButton = await page1.$(redirectButton);
    if (elementButton) {
      console.log("Selector found - redirectButton");    
      
      const newPagePromise = new Promise(resolve => {
        browser.once('targetcreated', target => resolve(target.page()));
        setTimeout(() => resolve(null), 5000); 
       });

      await elementButton.click();
      const newPage = await newPagePromise;

      if (newPage) {
          await newPage.waitForTimeout(15000); 
          await newPage.screenshot({ path: '2_tab.png', fullPage: true });
          console.log('2_tab - after clicking ...');
      } else {
          console.log('New page not created within the specified timeout'); //this is allways result !!!! :((((
      }
     
    } else {
      console.log("Selector did not find - redirectButton");
    }  
    
    await browser.close()

    console.log(`All done, check the screenshot`)
}

runView().catch((error) => console.error('Error in runViewBot:', error));
```

I tried a lot combinations with targetFilter, but with any result.